# Promesas autoejecutables con fetch

Tags: javascript, promesas, fetch

Estoy intentando crear un autoejecutable con una promesa en su interior y no termino de aclararme

```
let initTable = (function cargarDatatable (showCongeladas=false) {

    fetch(url, config)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((datos) => {
        // crea la datatable y otras cosas con los datos
    })
    return cargarDatatable;
})();
```

Mi idea es que cuando termine el `fetch` pueda volver a habilitar los botones entre otras cosas

```
//disable botones
initTable()
.then(()=> {
    // enable botones
})
```

He estado probando con `async` y `await` pero no termino de aclararme

Comment: Podrías utilizar un booleano. Inicializado a true. Cuando deba hacer esa funcion, antes del fetch lo pones a false. Y en el último then lo pones a true otra vez

Comment: Poniendole flags no es la solución, busco que el autoejecutable retorne una promesa despues de traerse los datos con fetch y trabajarlos.

Comment: si es un autoejecutable porque llamas `initTable().then` con devolver la promesa `fetch` en vez de `cargarDatatable` seria suficiente

Comment: @hawks Porque tengo que trabajar con esos datos y además cargar la datatable.
y fuera de initable habilito / deshabilito cosas mientras carga.

Comment: para aclararme quieres deshabilitar los botones mientras cargas los datos y cuando esten cargados habilitar los botones?

Comment: @hawks justamente eso, ya se que lo puedo hacer dentro del autoejecutable, pero era para saber como se retorna una promesa del fetch, suponiendo que se pueda tal como lo he planteado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno puedes hacerlo así. Puedes pasar los parametros a tu función [IIFE(Expresión de función ejecutada inmediatamente)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/IIFE) tal como se pasan a cualquier otra función cuando se invoca.

Pero la verdad es que no entiendo lo del autoejecutable, si se tiene que ejecutar solo una vez(en la carga de página) para ello tienes el evento `load`.

Creo que así la función `cargarDatatable` no es muy reusable.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('cargar');
let initTable = (function cargarDatatable (url, config, showCongeladas = false) {
    
    btn.disabled = true;
    // se devuelve la promesa para añadir el callback en el `then` y ejecutar el callback luego de la resolución de la promesa 
    return fetch(url, config)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((datos) => {
        // crea la datatable y otras cosas con los datos
        console.log(datos)
    })
})('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', /*tu config*/{ method: 'GET'});

// initTable es un objeto promesa y puedes añadir `then` 
initTable.then(() => {
  // esto se ejecutara luego de cargar los datos,
  btn.disabled = false;
})
```

```html
<button id="cargar">Cargar</button>
```

Comment: Lo has entendido bien y me has dado la solución. El autoejecutable también lo llego a llamar en un evento, lo del evento load lo desconocia, le echare un vistazo. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: de nada. Me alegra haberte ayudado

Answer (score 1):

Actualizo la respuesta de @hawks, que funciona perfectamente, para añadir la solución con el uso de `async`/`await`, del build-in de Javascript.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('load');
const loading = document.querySelector('#loading');

// Devuelve una Promise que se resuelve pasado 1 segundo
const initTable = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Emula la espera del fetch
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });

// Al poner la keyword async
// nos permite "awaitear" una Promise.
// Mientras se está resolviendo la Promise, el "hilo" se libera.
// Una vez la Promise se resuelve, la función se sigue ejecutando.
btn.addEventListener(`click`, async () => {
  startWait();
  await initTable();
  stopWait();
});


const startWait = () => {
  btn.disabled = true;
  loading.innerHTML = `Esperando respuesta ...`;
}

const stopWait = () => {
  btn.disabled = false;
  loading.innerHTML = ``;
}
```

```html
<button id="load">Cargar</button>
<p id="loading"></p>
```

En los comentarios hablo de hilos (*threads*) por el bien de la didáctica. Javascript no funciona con hilos de ejecución como tal, sinó con la *call stack* y el *event loop*, dejo un [link](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/) y un [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrNQS8J67zc)  que me parecen bastante más explicativos, por si quedan dudas.

Espero que sirva.